# Why isn't this axis or title showing up?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axes, radar-chart, multiple-axes

I'm working on creating a polar chart and I can't get everything to show up how I want it.

Can someone help me figure out why the axis and title at 2 o'clock isn't showing up? Any other tips to make this look better would be appreciated! Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

class Radar(object):

    def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
        if rect is None:
            rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

        self.n = len(titles)
        self.angles = np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)
        self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                         for i in range(self.n)]

        self.ax = self.axes[0]
        self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=12, weight="bold")

        for ax in self.axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

        for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
            ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 7), labels=label, angle=angle, fontsize=12)
            ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(0, 6) 

    def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
        angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
        values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
        self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

titles = [
    "Canada", "Australia",
    "New Zealand", "Japan", "China", "USA", "Mexico", "Finland", 
]

labels = [
    list("abcde"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"), 
    [" ", " ", "$156", "$158", "$160"],
    list("jklmn"), list("asdfg"), list("qwert"), [" ", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6"]
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3],  "--", lw=1, color="b", alpha=.5, label="USA 2014")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4],"-", lw=1, color="r", alpha=.5, label="2014")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3], "-", lw=1, color="g", alpha=.5, label="2013")
radar.plot([4.5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4], "-", lw=1, color="y", alpha=.5, label="2012")

radar.ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

fig = py.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 10, forward=True)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1)
```

and here's the image it produces:

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you define `radar.angles` with this line:

```
self.angles = np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)
```

you end up with the final angle being `>360.`:

```
print self.angles
>>> [  90.  135.  180.  225.  270.  315.  360.  405.]
```

You just need to assign the angles differently, to make sure they are all `<=360.`

For example, if you change the definition of `self.angles` to:

```
self.angles = [a if a <=360. else a - 360. for a in np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)]

print self.angles
>>> [  90.  135.  180.  225.  270.  315.  360.  45.]
```

then everything works fine:

[image]